# Grails 2.3.8 refreshing dependencies

Tags: grails

since today i'm getting an confusing error in ggts, while refreshing dependencies. I never had this error before and it says nothing to me:

```
Command terminated with an exception: java.lang.Exception (see details for 
partial output)
Command: GrailsCommand(P/project> compile --non-interactive --refresh-
dependencies)
---- System.out ----
Loading Grails 2.3.8
.
|Environment set to development
.Error 
|
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: _GrailsClasspath_groovy$_run_closure1
Error |
at _GrailsClasspath_groovy.run(_GrailsClasspath_groovy:39)
Error |
at _GrailsClasspath_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
Error |
at   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall
(CallSiteArray.java:45)
Error |
at _GrailsEvents_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
Error |
at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets.leftShift(IncludeTargets.groovy:59)
Error |
at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets$leftShift.call(Unknown Source)
Error |
at _GrailsEvents_groovy.run(_GrailsEvents_groovy:32)
Error |
at _GrailsEvents_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
Error |
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall
(CallSiteArray.java:45)
Error |
at _GrailsArgParsing_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
Error |
at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets.leftShift(IncludeTargets.groovy:59)
Error |
at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets$leftShift.call(Unknown Source)
Error |
at _GrailsArgParsing_groovy.run(_GrailsArgParsing_groovy:29)
Error |
at _GrailsArgParsing_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
Error |
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall 
(CallSiteArray.java:45)
Error |
at _GrailsInit_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
Error |
at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets.leftShift(IncludeTargets.groovy:59)
Error |
at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets$leftShift.call(Unknown Source)
Error |
at _GrailsInit_groovy.run(_GrailsInit_groovy:34)
Error |
at _GrailsInit_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
Error |
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall 
(CallSiteArray.java:45)
Error |
at _GrailsCompile_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
Error |
at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets.leftShift(IncludeTargets.groovy:59)
Error |
at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets$leftShift.call(Unknown Source)
Error |
at _GrailsCompile_groovy.run(_GrailsCompile_groovy:28)
Error |
at _GrailsCompile_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
Error |
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall 
(CallSiteArray.java:45)
Error |
at _GrailsSettings_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
Error |
at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets.leftShift(IncludeTargets.groovy:59)
Error |
at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets$leftShift.call(Unknown Source)
Error |
at Compile.run(Compile.groovy:25)
Error |
at Compile$run.call(Unknown Source)
Error |
at gant.Gant.prepareTargets(Gant.groovy:607)
Error |
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeWithGantInstance 
(GrailsScriptRunner.java:769)
Error |
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptFile 
(GrailsScriptRunner.java:571)
Error |
at 
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptWithCaching 
(GrailsScriptRunner.java:470)
Error |
at 
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptWithCaching 
(GrailsScriptRunner.java:421)
Error |
at org.grails.ide.api.impl.GrailsConnectorImpl.executeCommand 
(GrailsConnectorImpl.java:160)
Error |
at org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.process.GrailsProcess.run 
(GrailsProcess.java:130)
Error |
at org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.process.GrailsProcess.main 
(GrailsProcess.java:93)
Error |
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error |
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke 
(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error |
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke 
(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error |
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Error |
at 

org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader 
(GrailsStarter.ja
va:235)
Error |
at  
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main 
(GrailsStarter.java:263)
---- System.err ----
```

I didn't change the config of my project intentionally, don't know what happened. 
I run grails 2.3.8 with java is 1.7
If somebody knows what to do, please tell me!
Thanks in advance

Comment: try check compatibility of grails version with java version

Comment: its compatible. the project was running for 3 years until yesterday :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had to remove the script cache folder from project: https://www.javabrahman.com/error-handling/error-_grailsclasspath_groovy_run_closure1/

Answer (score 0):

is your grails SDK and jdk configured correctly ?

You can follow below steps:

1. Go to your project directory  `e.g. d:\YourProject`
2. Navigate to target\work folder in your project directory `e.g. d:\YourProject\target\work`
3. Delete the work folder
4. run commands   `grails clean` and `grails compile`

If still issue not solved : run command `grails clean-all` and right click on project in GGTS then click on refresh dependencies > download

Hope it helps you

Comment: thx for your answer, but i dont have any work folders in "target" and i can't run clean-all... looks like i cant run any grails commands :/ they all cause the errorlog above

Comment: @pebbles Ohhk, is your grails SDK and jdk configured correctly?

Comment: yeah guess so. JDK 1.7 and grails 2.3.8 is set in preferences of GGTS